# Jacocoant and sonar does not generate report

Tags: sonarqube

I have configured sonar with ant and it works fine now i am proceeding for integrating jacoco unit tests for my project.
I did the following configurations to achieve this:

```
<property name="project.test" location="${project.path}/test" />
<property name="project.target" location="${project.path}/target" />
<property name="project.reports" location="${project.target}/reports" />
<property name="project.reports.juint" location="${project.reports}/junit" />
<property name="sonar.tests" value="${project.test}" />
<property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" location="${reports.junit.xml.dir}" />
<property name="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="reuseReports" />
<property name="sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
<property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="target/jacoco.exec" />
<property name="sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
```

where "project.path" is my main project folder where i have my SRC and BUILD(containing class files) directories.

```
<target name="test" depends="compile">
<taskdef name="junit" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
</taskdef>


<jacoco:coverage destfile="target/jacoco.exec" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
<junit fork="yes" dir="${basedir}" failureProperty="test.failed">
    <classpath location="${project.build}" />
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />

    <formatter type="xml" />
    <batchtest todir="${reports.juint.xml.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${project.test}">
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
</jacoco:coverage>

</target>
```

But unfortunately every time i execute my build.xml i see the following error and everything except jacoco works, please could someone help me i need to run unit tests for my code using *jacocoant*

```
[sonar:sonar] 16:13:00.882 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 16:13:00.956 INFO  o.s.p.j.JaCoCoPlugin - Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: /archive/target/reports/junit/jacoco.exec
[sonar:sonar] 16:13:01.868 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 986 ms
```

please let me know if you need any further information

Comment: For a working example, go here: http://itestfirst.wordpress.com/2014/10/15/ant-sonar-and-jacoco-working-example/

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
<property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="target/jacoco.exec" />
```

be

```
<property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="${project.target}/jacoco.exec" />
```

given your properties above?